# Using The Extended Euclidean Algorithm :

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

How can I compute $d$ using The Extended Euclidean Algorithm:

$$d e \equiv 1~\text{mod}~\varphi ( n ) $$

If the value of $e$ and  $\text{mod}~\varphi ( n )$ are known as

$d_7 \equiv 1~\text{mod}~8  $

I'll appreciate any help or explanation .

Comment: Did I edit your question correctly?

Comment: @Arbuja , yes, thanks!